# passing data from a controller to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

does it exist a way to pass data from a controller to on other controller using php framework CodeIgniter?I mean I have some data in a controller and I would pass them to another controller....

Comment: Why not just pass the data to the model interacting with it instead of passing it around controllers?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry can you do that? Can you pass var1 to model1 from controller1 and retrieve var1 from model1 in controller2?

Comment: I agree @CharlesSprayberry, that is the very best thing to do.

Comment: Why would you even *need* to pass it off to another controller?  The controller shouldn't do anything more then get the appropriate data from the Model and pass it off to the View.  I guess I just don't see why you'd need to have 2 controllers working with the data when the Model should be doing the heavy processing.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry say the data had nothing to do with db interaction. Say a callback or an id for future selection. I'm curious about my other question too.

Comment: @stormdrain The Model has nothing to do with DB interaction either.  The Model is ultimately your app, whether or not you are using a database you are ultimately processing data...that should be done in the Model.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry According to the CodeIgniter docs, the Model is advised to be the place where db interaction takes place. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html I think that may be where my confusion is. That said, my first question still stands unanswered.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Never mind... I suppose it wasn't answered because it is *not* possible... You can not share data between controllers using models.

Comment: You can't load multiple controllers in a single MVC request. HMVC solves this problem, but is outside the core CI scope.  The model then has to use either a temporary or residual form of storage to persist the data across requests.  I would argue that MVC isn't sharing controllers between models, but the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Your question kind of defeats the purpose of the MVC pattern.  Controllers shouldn't have to "know about each other."  You might have serious coupling issues if that's the case.

If you can, try to "pass" information through the URI (which is statelessly RESTful) like @stormdrain suggests.  If you can't maintain statelessness, go with session data.

Session data is a little more suited for what you're doing, particularly if you need the application to "remember" something that happened earlier in the session.  CI has a pretty good internal library for this (though it's not without some documented flaws, fair warning):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Doesn't using the session limit you to 4kb of data though? If you're not using the db_session? I may be misunderstanding that too :)

Comment: That's correct. The browsers' cookie storage size becomes a limitation if not using a database

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` data will pass data along to another controller. You can also user params like so:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
    function page($param=""){
        echo $param;
    }
}
```

http://site.local/test/page/blah will give you a blank page with the word "blah". However, it's not a good idea to pass data via params outside of int's (like id's)... often you will have disallowed url characters if not using int's.